# Integral with branch cuts

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I want to integrate a function in complex plane along the vertical line with real part = c. The function has branch points at $0$,$k$ and $\infty$. I have chosen two branch cuts, as shown in the figure. Is the contour shown in dotted line a valid way to close this contour?
[image: Contour]

Comment: Valid yes. Whether it will allow you to compute the integral depends on the function.